# Facebook: Remote log out all sessions

Tags: facebook, security

How can I see the list of Facebook sessions and remotely log out from all sessions of **Facebook**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to **Account Settings**
   [image: Account Settings in the top left]
2. Go to **Security**
   [image: Security link under General]
3. Search for **Active Sessions** - the last section from below[image: Active Session in the main screen near the bottom]
4. Click on **Edit** on the right side
5. If you have more than the current session, the others will be displayed below the current one[image: List of all active sessions]
6. Click on **End Activity** for each session you want to close[image: End activity next to each session]

Answer (score 1):

One way to remotely log out from all sessions of Facebook at once is to [change the password](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=account). After the password change, Facebook asks whether you want to remotely log out from all sessions:

[image]